# How to Handle Blanks in %UserProfile% Batch File?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, path

I have created a script that copies our work PowerPoint Presentation Template from DropBox and saves it as the default template.

Some user accounts have spaces, others do not, and I cannot get the Batch file used to trigger this script to run.

I have tried every type of formatting I can think of for this line {}""'' etc

`"'%UserProfile%'\'Dropbox'\'Group Team Folder'\'Templates'\'PowerPoint Template.potx'"`

The expected result would be for the Batch file to use the blank in the username "John Smith" as part of the path to the PowerPoint template instead of cutting it off.

it spits out an error stating the path "C:\Users\John" is not recognized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

### Edit

```
@ECHO OFF

If exist "%UserProfile%\Dropbox\Group Team Folder\Templates\PowerPoint Template.potx" (
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "%UserProfile%\Dropbox\Group Team Folder\Templates\Script\Powerpoint Template.ps1"
)

If exist  "%UserProfile%\Dropbox (Group)\Group Team Folder\Templates\PowerPoint Template.potx" (
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "%UserProfile%\Dropbox\Group Team Folder\Templates\Script\Powerpoint Template.ps1"
)

PAUSE
```

Without single ticks, it does not work on the systems with a user profile with no spaces.
Note the reason the code is repeated is because there are 2 different directories for Dropbox on certain systems so it uses the PowerPoint template to determine if the path what path is correct for that system.

### Edit 2

`C:\Users\John\Dropbox\Group : The term 'C:\Users\John\Dropbox\Group' is not 
    recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
    function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
    if a path was included, verify that the
    path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:1
    + C:\Users\John\Dropbox\Group Team Folder\Templates\ ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

That is my command prompt error.

I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: You need to to show us the command you are using this in. And remove the single-quotes.

Comment: Remove all the single ticks and leave the surrounding double quotes.

Comment: Removing the single ticks stops the script from working on systems without the spaces, as well as the ones that contain spaces

Comment: We are giving you the plain simple truth when it comes to anything with spaces in a batch file. Surround with double quotes. Until you show us all of your script there is no way for us to help you.

Comment: I updated with the entire script and I wish It was a matter of removing the single ticks -_-

Comment: Single quotes have no meaning in batch outside of `for /f` loops. I do not believe that removing them is giving you an issue. Also, keeping double quotes around a path that doesn't need them will have no impact whatsoever.

Comment: That error is coming from your powershell script.

Comment: It wasn't the script, it always ran fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the usual ways to run a powershell script;

using `-File`:

```ps1
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%UserProfile%\Dropbox\Group Team Folder\Templates\Script\Powerpoint Template.ps1"
```

using `-Command`:

```ps1
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%UserProfile%\Dropbox\Group Team Folder\Templates\Script\Powerpoint Template.ps1'"
```

Comment: This solved it, by formatting it as - file instead of - command. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some users trying to copy files from\to their profiles.

I end up using for windows 8.1 the $env variables.

```
$env:systemDrive\users\$env:USERNAME
```

but I see you want to run a PowerShell script there so Compo give you the hint on how to run those.